# docker compose file giving an invalid type error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
 environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
```

however, I am getting this error when I run docker-compose up:

The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.environment.MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null

I don't really understand why I'm getting this error because I've seen other examples of docker compose files with the value set to true. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out. Looks like I needed to change "true" to 1. Here's my final file which works now:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
 environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a boolean value, that's why you are getting this error. "true" (without the quotes) gets converted to True, which is a boolean value.

Looking at the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) page it says it only has to be a non-empty value.